# Bxslider error InvalidPointerId on Android 6.0.1

Tags: javascript, bxslider

Bxslider ([git code here](https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4)) was working all nicely on Android. Today when I slide the carousel  it fires this error "Invalid Pointer Id: Failed to execute 'set Pointer Capture' on 'Element': Invalid Pointer Id."
Looking at the bxslider script this is the code where the error fires:

```
if (slider.viewport.get(0).setPointerCapture) {
  slider.pointerId = orig.pointerId;
  slider.viewport.get(0).setPointerCapture(slider.pointerId);
}
```

Any clue on what is going on?

Comment: I've tested the apk on Genymotion emulator on Android 6.0 API 23 and it works as expected. Can I trust the emulator? Why on Nexus 7 is giving me the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a workaround that works. Use this snippet of code:

```
var chromePointerEvents = typeof PointerEvent === 'function'; if (chromePointerEvents) { if (orig.pointerId === undefined) { return; } }
```

Insert after:

```
touchPoints = (typeof orig.changedTouches !== 'undefined') ? orig.changedTouches : [orig];
```

of file jquery.bxslider.js